# Counting conccurent user sessions by time bins/intervals

Tags: python, pandas, intervals

My data is made up of sessions with start and end timestamps.  My task is to count the number of sessions by company and app version that are 'active' for each interval.  I'm starting with an interval of 2 minutes.  Thus if a Company has a session that lasts from  2:00pm to 2:07pm... that Company would count in each of the 4 bins/intervals (2:00, 2:02, 2:04, 2:06). How would I go about solving this with pandas?

this is my sample data:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({
    'Customer': ["CompanyA", "CompanyB", "CompanyA", "CompanyC", "CompanyB", "CompanyB", "CompanyC", "CompanyA", "CompanyC", "CompanyB"],   
    'AppVer': ["zi1","zi3","zi2","zi2","zi1","zi3","zi3","zi2","zi1","zi1"], 
    'start_timestamp': pd.date_range(start='2020-06-01 22:19:00', freq='3min', periods=10),
    'end_timestamp': pd.date_range(start='2020-06-01 22:23:00', freq='4min', periods=10)
}).sample(frac=1)#randomize rows

print(data)
```

I was able to count based on the 2 minute intervals

```
session_starts = (x - pd.Timedelta(seconds=x.second) for x in data['start_timestamp'])
session_ends = (x - pd.Timedelta(seconds=x.second) for x in data['end_timestamp'])
sesszip = zip(session_starts,session_ends)
ranges_gen = (pd.date_range(x.round("2T"),y.round("2T"),freq='2T') for x,y in sesszip)
ranges_ser = pd.Series(chain.from_iterable(ranges_gen),name="time")
output_df = ranges_ser.value_counts(sort=False)\
.sort_index()\
.to_frame()\
.reset_index()\
.rename(columns={'index':'time' , 'time':'counts'})

output_df
```

I'm now having trouble figuring out how to  group by the Customer or App Version.  Any help or thoughts on a different approach would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: With your data sample `session_starts` and `session_ends` do nothing because seconds are already `0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, we can recreate your `output_df` using this:

```
data['timerange'] = data.apply(lambda x: 
                              pd.date_range(x['start_timestamp'].floor('T').round('2T'), 
                                           x['end_timestamp'].floor('T').round('2T'), 
                                           freq='2T'), 
                               axis=1)

data.explode('timerange').groupby(['timerange'])['Customer'].count()
```

Output:

```
timerange
2020-06-01 22:20:00    1
2020-06-01 22:22:00    2
2020-06-01 22:24:00    3
2020-06-01 22:26:00    2
2020-06-01 22:28:00    3
2020-06-01 22:30:00    2
2020-06-01 22:32:00    3
2020-06-01 22:34:00    3
2020-06-01 22:36:00    4
2020-06-01 22:38:00    3
2020-06-01 22:40:00    4
2020-06-01 22:42:00    3
2020-06-01 22:44:00    4
2020-06-01 22:46:00    4
2020-06-01 22:48:00    4
2020-06-01 22:50:00    3
2020-06-01 22:52:00    3
2020-06-01 22:54:00    2
2020-06-01 22:56:00    2
2020-06-01 22:58:00    1
2020-06-01 23:00:00    1
Name: Customer, dtype: int64
```

By Customer:

```
data.explode('timerange').groupby(['Customer','timerange'])['Customer'].count().unstack(0, fill_value=0)
```

Output:

```
Customer             CompanyA  CompanyB  CompanyC
timerange                                        
2020-06-01 22:20:00         1         0         0
2020-06-01 22:22:00         1         1         0
2020-06-01 22:24:00         2         1         0
2020-06-01 22:26:00         1         1         0
2020-06-01 22:28:00         1         1         1
2020-06-01 22:30:00         1         0         1
2020-06-01 22:32:00         1         1         1
2020-06-01 22:34:00         0         2         1
2020-06-01 22:36:00         0         2         2
2020-06-01 22:38:00         0         2         1
2020-06-01 22:40:00         1         2         1
2020-06-01 22:42:00         1         1         1
2020-06-01 22:44:00         1         1         2
2020-06-01 22:46:00         1         1         2
2020-06-01 22:48:00         1         1         2
2020-06-01 22:50:00         1         1         1
2020-06-01 22:52:00         1         1         1
2020-06-01 22:54:00         0         1         1
2020-06-01 22:56:00         0         1         1
2020-06-01 22:58:00         0         1         0
2020-06-01 23:00:00         0         1         0
```

And by AppVer:

```
data.explode('timerange').groupby(['AppVer','timerange'])['AppVer'].count().unstack(0, fill_value=0)
```

Output:

```
AppVer               zi1  zi2  zi3
timerange                         
2020-06-01 22:20:00    1    0    0
2020-06-01 22:22:00    1    0    1
2020-06-01 22:24:00    1    1    1
2020-06-01 22:26:00    0    1    1
2020-06-01 22:28:00    0    2    1
2020-06-01 22:30:00    0    2    0
2020-06-01 22:32:00    1    2    0
2020-06-01 22:34:00    1    1    1
2020-06-01 22:36:00    1    1    2
2020-06-01 22:38:00    1    0    2
2020-06-01 22:40:00    1    1    2
2020-06-01 22:42:00    0    1    2
2020-06-01 22:44:00    1    1    2
2020-06-01 22:46:00    2    1    1
2020-06-01 22:48:00    2    1    1
2020-06-01 22:50:00    2    1    0
2020-06-01 22:52:00    2    1    0
2020-06-01 22:54:00    2    0    0
2020-06-01 22:56:00    2    0    0
2020-06-01 22:58:00    1    0    0
2020-06-01 23:00:00    1    0    0
```

Comment: Thanks this works. Is this possible without a lambda?  when i apply to the full data set it's taking a long time.  I'm worried it wont scale well at 1+ Million sessions daily.

Comment: It will not scale well.  Let me look at it a bit longer and see if there is a way.